# registering for device notifications

Tags: visual-c++

so iv'e been searching for a way to get notifications when a USB device is connected to the pc. i found this code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devio/registering-for-device-notification
now i have a few problems with this code(visual c++).
I tried putting it in my visual c++ 2017 but it won't compile. there are 6 errors in 2 types:
lines 330, 344, 495: error E0167.
'argument of type "PTSTR" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" '
https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%2B%2B%20argument+of+type+%22PTSTR%22+is+incompatible+with+parameter+of+type+%22LPCWSTR%22
lines 330, 350, 495: error C2664.
"'LPWSTR *CommandLineToArgvW(LPCWSTR,int *)': cannot convert argument 1/3 from 'PTSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2664?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2664)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2017

before line 330 there is a comment that says to add Windows to the project. i did that but I'm still getting these errors, and searching them in the web didn't help since i do understand the error but have no idea how to fix it. I would highly appreciate it if you could help me compile this code. thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to post the lines of code giving the errors and the exact text of the errors not just the error numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, that example code is poorly written. It is mixing things like `PWSTR` with `LPTSTR`. `PWSTR` is a pointer to a wide-character string whereas `LPTSTR` is a pointer to either a character string or a wide-character string depending on the project settings.

Since the code is using wide-character strings in some places and calling functions that end with `W`, you need to configure the project to use wide-character strings for everything. I don't have VS 2017, but in VS 2015 you configure your project to use wide-character strings by setting *Project->Properties->General->Character Set* to **Use Unicode Character Set**.

**EDIT**: To answer your comment.

The problem you are having is primarily due to line 13:

```
PWSTR g_pszAppName;
```

This is one of two variables declared explicitly as a wide-character string pointer. You can try to modify the code not to use any wide character strings as follows:

Change line 13 to:

```
PTSTR g_pszAppName = _T("MyApp");   // Put your app name here
```

Remove these 2 lines (330 and 331):

```
PWSTR* ppArgV = CommandLineToArgvW(lpstrCmdLine, &nArgC);
g_pszAppName = ppArgV[0];
```

You may also want to change *Project->Properties->General->Character Set* back to what it was originally.

Comment: Jim Rhodes, first of all thanks for the help.
I tried doing as you said but unfortunately it did not fix any of the errores.
about the code being poorly written, is there a better source where i can learn from how to do this? I'm trying to make a code that can catch all kinds of events from windows, but the basics for me are managing USB devices. After quite a long search this is the best code source that i could find on the internet.
thx again, shon ;)

Comment: THANKS A LOT! PROBLEM SOLVED! one last question, where did u learn winapi? would be awesome if u could send a link or something.

thx for everything, -shon ;)